# How can you visualize the audio level within a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to make a UIImageView fill with color based on how much sound there is. The level of sound should indicate the height that the color fills up in the image.

How can I visualize the audio level like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Listings/AudioViews_LevelMeter_m.html for an example of how to draw in response to audio level. It isn't identical to your proposed interface but the underlying principles (redrawing in response to level metering) are exactly the same.